# TypeScript and split namespace

Tags: typescript

`tsconfig.json`:

```
...
"module": "none"
...
```

`file1.ts`:

```
namespace Myns {
  type Mytype = number
}
```

`file2.ts`:

```
namespace Myns {
  let x: Mytype
         ^^^^^^ Unable to find declaration in file1.ts
}
```

Why I can't use `Mytype` inside `file2.ts` without exporting it in `file1.ts`? I don't want it to be exported. Using TS 3.8 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to docs

[reference tags are needed when there are dependencies between files](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html)

```js
/// <reference path="file1.ts" />
namespace Myns {
  let x: Mytype
}
```

--Edit
Forgot about the main thing, we have to export type to use it anywhere

```js
namespace Myns {
  export type Mytype = number
}
```

Comment: Still getting an error: file2.ts:4:12 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Mytype'.

Comment: That was my question why I heed export, it is the same namesapace? Is it a bug?

Comment: Well in documentation they exported the types and used them in other files with namespace so I think its the general practice

Comment: TS is a great technology, but this need for export to use inside the same NS is a clear Microsoft touche.